# Using gsub to replace "=>" with ":" in an array of hashes

Tags: json, ruby, parsing, hash, gsub

I think I've written myself in a corner. Basically, I have an array of hashes, like so.

```
 my_hashes = [{"colorName"=>"first", "hexValue"=>"#f00"}, {"colorName"=>"green", "hexValue"=>"#0f0"}, 
    {"colorName"=>"blue", "hexValue"=>"#00f"}, {"colorName"=>"cyan", "hexValue"=>"#0ff"}, 
    {"colorName"=>"magenta", "hexValue"=>"#f0f"}, {"colorName"=>"yellow", "hexValue"=>"#ff0"}, 
    {"colorName"=>"black", "hexValue"=>"#000"}]
```

I need to use JSON.parse to eventually be able to transform these hashes into CSV format. The only problem is I can't get JSON.parse to work as long as the "=>" symbol is present. I've tried just doing a regular gsub('=>', ':') but it appears that I cannot use it as this is an array of hashes. I've tried variations of the following method:

```
my_hashes.each do |hash| 
    hash.each do |key, value|
        key.gsub!('=>', ':')
        value.gsub!('=>', ':')
    end
end
```

I need these hash values to stay intact, so even if I transform them intro strings, if I transform them back they'll still have the '=>' symbol available. Any advice?

Comment: Just use `my_hashes.to_json` to transform it into a JSON string. You may need to `require 'json'` first.

Comment: Why convert the hash to JSON and then CSV? Why not go straight to CSV using [`csv` from the standard library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/index.html)?

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Instead of converting the hashes you need to describe what you're trying to do, then look at a better way to accomplish it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I have found a way to solve the problem, and am working on refactoring the code now.

Answer (score 2):

Changing `=>` to `:` wouldn't make a Ruby hash to a JSON object. And in fact you cannot just change a hash like that at all. Because the written representation of a hash is not the same as the interpreted version in memory.

But that doesn't solve your problem: You need a `JSON` representation of a Ruby hash, just use `to_json`:

```
my_hashes = [
 {"colorName"=>"first", "hexValue"=>"#f00"}, 
 {"colorName"=>"green", "hexValue"=>"#0f0"}, 
 {"colorName"=>"blue", "hexValue"=>"#00f"}, 
 {"colorName"=>"cyan", "hexValue"=>"#0ff"}, 
 {"colorName"=>"magenta", "hexValue"=>"#f0f"}, 
 {"colorName"=>"yellow", "hexValue"=>"#ff0"}, 
 {"colorName"=>"black", "hexValue"=>"#000"}
]

require 'json'
my_hashes.to_json
#=> "[{"colorName":"first","hexValue":"#f00"},{"colorName":"green","hexValue":"#0f0"},{"colorName":"blue","hexValue":"#00f"},{"colorName":"cyan","hexValue":"#0ff"},{"colorName":"magenta","hexValue":"#f0f"},{"colorName":"yellow","hexValue":"#ff0"},{"colorName":"black","hexValue":"#000"}]"
```

Comment: Yes, you're totally correct. Hopefully I've wised up a bit more after working with JSON a bit.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_hashes=[{"colorName"=>"first", "hexValue"=>"#f00"}]

new_data = my_hashes.to_json.gsub(/\=\>/, ':')

data = Json.parse new_data
```

Comment: You could improve this answer by providing some explanation, rather than just code.

Comment: The `gsub` call is useless, because there are no `=>` in the json created by `to_json`.